# Spark - iterative deduplication

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a below situation where i am stuck with framing the problem in spark sql. Below is the description.

### Input

Suppose there are 3 columns in a spark df. (id_a , id_b, score_val ). Below is a sample data:

| id_a | id_b | score_val |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 5000 | 10.5 |
| 1000 | 5001 | 10.4 |
| 2000 | 5000 | 10.9 |
| 2000 | 5001 | 10.3 |
| 3000 | 5000 | 11.1 |
| 3000 | 5001 | 11.0 |
| 3000 | 5002 | 10.8 |

### Expected output

The ask is to deduplicate this dataset in a two way fashion. In this case, the output after deduplication should be as follows-

| id_a | id_b | score_val |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 5000 | 10.5 |
| 2000 | 5001 | 10.3 |
| 3000 | 5002 | 10.8 |

### Explanation

- for `id_a = 1000`, the program should pick out highest score_val record, in this case, the row with `id_b = 5000`
- for `id_a = 2000`, the program should pick out row with `id_b = 5001`, since id_b=5000 has been previously mapped to `id_a = 1000`
- for `id_a = 3000`, the program should pick out row with `id_b = 5002`, since `id_b = 5000` has been previously mapped to `id_a = 1000`, and
  `id_b = 5001` has been previously mapped to `id_a = 2000`

I have tried previously to use window function to traverse the rows and pick out the correct output.But i have been stuck and couldnt
proceed. I have rewritten this to use MapPartitions feature of spark dataframe and implement a custom dedupe logic in core java.
However its not optimal performance-wise.

If someone has any clue how to solve this problem of simultaneous filter+deduplication operation using spark sql construct,
it  will be greatly be appreciated!

Comment: I'm afraid that Spark isn't well suited for what you are trying to do: it doesn't seem like a computation that can be parallelized. If I get it correctly, you need to compute the result for the group id_a=1000 before being able to compute it for the group id_a=2000, before computing it for id_a=3000, and so on.... Imagine you have 1M such groups for id_a, you will have to compute them all sequentially... Perhaps you should try explaining your broader problem, and another way of solving it will come up... (cf: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 0):

Sort the dataset based on `id_b` in ascending order and then `score_val` in desending order.

E.g.,

```
sort(col("id_b").asc(),col("score_val").desc())
```